# Is this enum declaration a standard compliant?

Tags: c++, c, enums

So normally enum's are for declaring group of "constant integers" as another type, that represents something. Eg.

```
enum Color {RED=0, BLUE, YELLOW};
```

This is clear. But recently I met following in code. This was in a compiler for embedded systems.

```
enum State {DISABLED=0, ENABLED=!DISABLED};
```

And it worked just fine. It behaved as a boolean type. My question is, wheather it (this syntax) is ANSI compliant?

If it is standard compliant, then why would compilers define internally something like _Bool for boolean representation and then in `stdbool.h` (for C language) they do:

```
#define bool _Bool
... // here goes definitions of true and false
```

instead of

```
enum bool {false=0, true=!false};
```

Which is much cleaner?

Comment: ANSI compliant? That's a phrase I haven't heard for a while.

Comment: @DawidPi C and C++ are different languages, and subtle issues like this pretty much never get a good answer that covers both languages at the same time. If you really want to know for both languages, please ask them as separate questions.

Comment: @AlanStokes If you have an issue with an edit I made that I specifically explained in the comments, it seems quite rude to just revert it without any comment. I don't want to get into a rollback war about this, but as far as I'm concerned, this question was too broad in its original state, and if you're going to hinder attempts to get it in proper shape, fine, I'll just vote to close. (Which does of course not at all mean that it will actually end up closed.)

Comment: @hvd Is this reasonable at all? I wondered about two languages, that in this case replies to both, are very similar. After your hint I removed C++ flag, but just after answer appeared and covered also the part of C++, then I restored C++ flag, as answer would not be suitable. What should I do then?

Comment: @hvd Question clearly covers both; changing it to not do so doesn't seem to me to preserve the spirit. (I didn't see your comment at the time, not sure why.)

Comment: @DawidPi Yeah, that's a bit of a messy situation, if you asked two questions in one, and actually got an answer that addresses your two questions, then it kind of makes sense to leave it as it is. There are actually relevant details for C++ that aren't part of the current answers that I would have liked to put in one, but they don't make any sense for C...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the declaration is perfectly valid and portable in both C and C++.

In both C and C++, this:

```
enum State {DISABLED=0, ENABLED=!DISABLED};
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
enum State {DISABLED=0, ENABLED=1};
```

and to this:

```
enum State {DISABLED, ENABLED};
```

but for subtly different reasons.

In C, the unary `!` operator yields a result of type `int`, with value either `0` (if the operand is not equal to `0`) or `1` (if the operand is equal to `0`). `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0`.  (Any non-zero value is treated as true when used as a condition, but the `!` and `==` operators, among others always yield a result of exactly `0` or `1`.) Enumeration constants are always of type `int`; if a value is specified, it's converted to `int` if necessary.

(C added type `_Bool` in the 1999 standard, but all operators that yield logically "boolean" values still yield results of type `int`.)

In C++, the result of the unary `!` operator is of type `bool`. The result is `false` or `true` where C's `!` operator would yield `0` or `1`, respectively.  As in C, if a value is specified, it's converted as needed; the `bool` values `false` and `true` convert to `0` and `1`, respectively.

In C, enumeration constants are always of type `int`.  In C++, they're of the enumeration type, in this case `enum State`.

Referring to an earlier enumeration constant within the same type declaration is legal. Each enumeration constant becomes visible after it's declared.

As for something like:

```
enum bool { false = 0, true = !false );
```

being clearer than

```
enum bool { false = 0, true = 1 };
```

(in C; it would be illegal in C++), I respectfully disagree. The constant `1` is perfectly clear to anyone familiar with C. Rewriting it as `!false` is not helpful. In fact, when `<stdbool.h>` is not available (something that's rare these days), I've used:

```
typedef enum { false, true } bool;
```

The fact that `false` and `true` will be given their correct values is IMHO sufficiently obvious.

As for why C99 didn't use an `enum` definition like that, I suspect it's because each enumeration type is compatible with some implementation-defined integer type. (For gcc, it's usually `unsigned int` or `int`.) The committee wanted `_Bool` to be a distinct type with a conversion rank lower than any other integer type. (And they couldn't make `bool` a keyword without breaking existing code.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is standard-compliant.

`!DISABLED` is a valid *constant* expression, which is all that is required for an `enum` value.

```
enum State {DISABLED=0, ENABLED= (!DISABLED)};
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

At the point where `DISABLED` is referenced, the compiler knows its value, so it can compute the value of the expression derived from it, i.e. `!DISABLED`. It is a fancy way of writing `ENABLED=1`.

Comment: And is there any valid reason to one just write `ENABLED = 1` (where even the `= 1` may be redundant unless you want to make it "clear")

Comment: "It is a fancy way of writing `ENABLED=1` is not correct.   Given that an enum is actually a 'int' in size, and that '!DISABLED' does not mean add 1 but rather 'not 0' , which is directly punched into the code whereever the compiler sees 'ENABLED'

Comment: @user3629249: As far as C goes: *“The result of the logical negation operator
!
is 0 if the value of its operand compares
unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0.  The result has type
int
.
The expression
!E
is equivalent to
(0==E)”* (from a C11 draft). So yes, it is a fancy way of writing `ENABLED=1` in C. You seem to be talking about macros with “directly punched into the code”, which are not at all the same as enums.

Comment: To me, this indicates that the C11 draft has re-defined the meaning of `!value`  and in this case, the comparison would be: (0 ==0)  which would be 'true', but not necessarily =1.  especially as 'true' can be any value (in an evaluation, not in the definition of 'true') other than 0.  (That is one of the reasons that a comparison should NEVER be against 'true' And I have used compilers where 'true' was defined as -1 (0xFFFFFFFF)  and another where 'true' was defined as 2, all as builtin definitions of 'true', not some header file like `stdbool.h`

Comment: @user3629249: C11 did not change the meaning of `!value`.

Comment: @user3629249 Unless I'm mistaken, non-zero values are treated as truthy in conditionals (`if`, `?:`, etc.), but logical operators will always evaluate to either `0` or `1`. This is why the standard `int x = !!b` trick works.

Answer (score 3):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list

The same is valid in C++ (3.3.2 Point of declaration)

> 5 The point of declaration for an enumerator is immediately after its
>   enumerator-definition.[ Example:

```
const int x = 12;
{ enum { x = x }; }
```

> Here, the enumerator x is initialized with the value of the constant
>   x, namely 12. —end example ]

So you may use already defined enumerators in definitions of next enumerators in an enumeration.

As for the C type `_Bool` then it appeared in the C 99. Before this standard there are used either manifest constants or enumerations in C.

There is no sense to define an enumeration like this

```
enum bool {false=0, true!=false};
```

because type `_Bool` is already has two values 0 and 1.